# How To Change Div Style By Div ID

Tags: javascript, html

*Edit: Added JS below, per user comments. [Here is a great example](https://www.desiringgod.org/messages/the-path-to-full-and-lasting-pleasure) of what I am trying to accomplish:*

On a single blog page, I would like to have two buttons, “Audio” (div id=“audio”) and “Video” (div id=“video”).

By default Video would be enabled and display a video player within a div. If the user clicks Audio the browser changes the end of the URL to #audio which triggers a div style change. That would cause the Video player to be hidden and the Audio player to become visible. Likewise, if the user clicks Video again the end of the URL changes to #video which triggers a div style change and the Audio player to become hidden and the Video player to become visible.

Quite a bit of research has led me to being able to toggle a single div on and off, but I cannot figure out how to accomplish what I laid out above.

Here are my div statements.

When URL ends in #video

```
<div id="video" style="position: static; visibility: visible; overflow: visible; display: block;">MY VIDEO PLAYER</div>

<div id="audio" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; display: block;">MY AUDIO PLAYER</div>
```

When URL ends in #audio

```
<div id="video" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; display: block;">MY VIDEO PLAYER</div>

<div id="audio" style="position: static; visibility: visible; overflow: visible; display: block;">MY AUDIO PLAYER</div>
```

I am not even going to bother posting my javascript for this. It only works to toggle a single div on and off. I should mention, I am not a coder, but have come along ways on my journey and this site has always been a goto for me. First time question.

Thanks so much in advance for any assistance this outstanding site can provide.

Edit: Here is the js I used which only allows the toggle of a single div

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("video");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: reddit's /r/learnprogramming should be your first goto, you'd get slaughtered here. But please do post your js, the others will appreciate that and they will be less likely to be pissy "because you've done your homework"

Comment: In line with [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52106774/870729) (using CSS), I would indeed suggest posting your javascript here.  It will tell us a lot about what you're doing, and how we can best help.

Comment: I'd suggest that you move the inline style declaration out of the divs into a separate CSS file. If you want to make anything dynamic, inline style definitions only make things more difficult by a magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought, though I’m unable to check currently, would be to use the following stylesheet rules:

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#audio,
#video {
  /* hide both elements by default: */
  visibility: hidden;
}

#audio:target,
#video:target {
  /* show the element whose id is the
         document's hash (‘at the end of
         the URL’) */
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#video">Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#audio">Audio</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="video">MY VIDEO PLAYER</div>
  <div id="audio">MY AUDIO PLAYER</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tsu526fz/2/).

This does, of course, rely on CSS rather than JavaScript, though; so this may not be the answer you want.

Following the comment left by the OP:

> Unfortunately, I need video to be visible by default. Then if the user clicks audio, video would become hidden.

The following code works:

```css
/* aesthetics, irrelevant to the actual demo */
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.wrapper>div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 5em;
}


/* using 'display: flex' to allow the use of the
   'order' property on the chilren of this element: */
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

/* hiding the child elements of the wrapper by default: */
.wrapper>div {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* selecting the child of the .wrapper element with
   the class of 'defaultOnLoad', placing it first
   in the visual order of its parent with the
   'order: -1' property; and making it visible on
   page-load: */
.wrapper>.defaultOnLoad {
  order: -1;
  visibility: visible;
}


/* selecting the '.defaultOnLoad' element that
   is a general (later) sibling of an element
   that is the ':target' (whose id appears following
   the '#' in the URL), both of which are children of
   '.wrapper' and hiding that element: */
.wrapper> :target~.defaultOnLoad {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* finding the child of the '.wrapper' element that
   is the ':target' of the document and making it
   visible: */
.wrapper>:target {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#video">Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#audio">Audio</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- in the CSS we'll be selecting/styling the '.defaultOnLoad' element based
       on the state of another sibling being the ':target'; as CSS cannot select
       previous-siblings I've moved the '#video' to be the last child of the
       '.wrapper', but used CSS to maintain the visual order: -->
  <div id="audio">MY AUDIO PLAYER</div>
  <div id="video" class="defaultOnLoad">MY VIDEO PLAYER</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tsu526fz/1/).

As a demonstration for why I would recommend CSS over JavaScript, when CSS is able to perform the task, see the following, in which multiple other media options are added and no CSS changes are required:

```css
/* aesthetics, irrelevant to the actual demo */
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.wrapper>div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 5em;
}
/* using 'display: flex' to allow the use of the
   'order' property on the chilren of this element: */
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
/* hiding the child elements of the wrapper by default: */
.wrapper>div {
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* selecting the child of the .wrapper element with
   the class of 'defaultOnLoad', placing it first
   in the visual order of its parent with the
   'order: -1' property; and making it visible on
   page-load: */
.wrapper>.defaultOnLoad {
  order: -1;
  visibility: visible;
}
/* selecting the '.defaultOnLoad' element that
   is a general (later) sibling of an element
   that is the ':target' (whose id appears following
   the '#' in the URL), both of which are children of
   '.wrapper' and hiding that element: */
.wrapper> :target~.defaultOnLoad {
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* finding the child of the '.wrapper' element that
   is the ':target' of the document and making it
   visible: */
.wrapper>:target {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#video">Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#audio">Audio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#print">Print</a></li>
    <li><a href="#braille">Braille</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- in the CSS we'll be selecting/styling the '.defaultOnLoad' element based
       on the state of another sibling being the ':target'; as CSS cannot select
       previous-siblings I've moved the '#video' to be the last child of the
       '.wrapper', but used CSS to maintain the visual order: -->
  <div id="audio">MY AUDIO PLAYER</div>
  <div id="print">The 'print' option</div>
  <div id="braille">The 'braille' option</div>
  <div id="video" class="defaultOnLoad">MY VIDEO PLAYER</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tsu526fz/3/).

With regards to the comment, below, from the OP:

> One issue I am running into is the ID obviously causes the browser to jump. Is there some syntax I am not aware of that would keep the browser in place? …I need each of those DIV elements (audio/video) to replace one another without jumping or moving one below the other when a user clicks either audio or video.

There doesn't seem to be a CSS means of preventing the page scrolling to the position of the targeted elements – the `#video` and `#audio` – this may prevent the use of `<a>` elements, unfortunately; there is an alternative, using `<label>` and `<input>` elements, but this has the complication of adding extra HTML elements for the functionality:

```css
/* aesthetics, irrelevant to the actual demo */
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* giving an arbitrarily large margin-bottom to
   demonstrate that there is no default scrolling
   on clicking the <label>: */
nav {
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}
/* a <label> element doesn't have default styling to imply
   its interactive nature, so here we style the cursor to
   depict that it can be clicked: */
nav label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
/* hiding the <div> children contained within the .wrapper
   element: */
.wrapper>div {
  height: 5em;
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* selecting the <div> elements that are the immediate sibling
   of an <input> whose 'type' attribute is equal to 'radio' and
   which matches the ':checked' pseudo-class, and setting their
   visibility to 'visible': */
.wrapper input[type=radio]:checked + div {
  visibility: visible;
}
/* hiding the <input> elements: */
.wrapper input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <!-- using <label> elements instead of <a>; using the 'for'
         (HTMLLabelElement.HTMLFor property) to associate the
         <label> with the relevant <input> (the 'for' attribute
         must be equal to the 'id' attribute/property of the
         <input>: -->
    <li><label for="video">Video</label></li>
    <li><label for="audio">Audio</label></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- we place the <input> as the previous sibling of the relevant
       <div> element (although this is a convenience in order to
       simplify the selector): -->
  <input type="radio" name="mediaChoice" id="video" checked="checked" />
  <div id="video">MY VIDEO PLAYER</div>
  <input type="radio" name="mediaChoice" id="audio" />
  <div id="audio">MY AUDIO PLAYER</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tsu526fz/4/).

A further revision of the above, this time to use JavaScript:

```js
let nav = document.querySelector('nav'),
  mediaContainer = document.querySelector('div.wrapper'),
  // because one option needs to be shown on page-load, and
  // the user's ability to choose the media is determined
  // via the click event, here we have to create a click
  // event (a new MouseEvent), which can bubble through
  // the DOM to be detected by an ancestor:
  clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'bubbles': true
  });

// named function to handle events; the EventObject
// ('event') is passed automagically from the 
// EventTarget.addEventListener() method:
function mediaToggle(event) {

  // preventing the default behaviour of the
  // HTMLAnchorElement (which prevents the link
  // being 'followed' and prevents page-jumping):
  event.preventDefault();

  // here we retrieve the hash (the '#identifier'
  // fragment) of the clicked (event.target) <a>
  // element:
  let selector = event.target.hash;
  
  // here we retrieve the NodeList of all '.media'
  // elements in the document; and use
  // NodeList.forEach() to iterate over that collection:
  document.querySelectorAll('.media').forEach(
  
    // we're using an Arrow function here; 'elem' is a
    // reference to the current element-node of the NodeList
    // over which we're iterating:
    (elem) => {
    
      // here we perform this function for all nodes;
      // using the Element.classList API  to toggle the
      // 'active' class; the switch which follows determines
      // whether the class-name is added, retained, removed or
      // or left off. The 'switch' is a condition which evaluates
      // to a true/false (or truthy/falsey) result:
      elem.classList.toggle('active',
        // here we use Element.matches(CSSSelector) to test whether
        // the current element-node matches the supplied CSS selector;
        // if it does the class-name is added (or retained), if not
        // the class-name is removed (or not-added):
        elem.matches(selector));
    });
}

// adding the mediaToggle() function - note the deliberate lack of
// parentheses - as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
nav.addEventListener('click', mediaToggle);

// using Element.querySelector() to find the first/only element
// that matches the supplied CSS selector
nav.querySelector('.defaultOnLoad')
  // firing the created MouseEvent on that element via
  // the EventTarget.dispatchEvent() method:
  .dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.media {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.media.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <!-- using the 'defaultOnLoad' class-name to identify which media
         should be the default on page-load: -->
    <li><a href="#video" class="defaultOnLoad">Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#audio">Audio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#print">Print</a></li>
    <li><a href="#braille">Braille</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="video" class="media">Video</div>
  <div id="audio" class="media">Audio</div>
  <div id="print" class="media">Print</div>
  <div id="braille" class="media">Braille</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tsu526fz/6/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).
  - [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).
  - [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).
  - [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).
  - [`MouseEvent()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent).
  - [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Comment: I did not know about this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp . A whole new world has opened up for me.

Comment: This looks promising David. Unfortunately, I need video to be visible by default. Then if the user clicks audio, video would become hidden. Your code works great otherwise.

Comment: David, thank you and everyone else for chiming in here. I am much more familiar with CSS, so I like this solution so far. One issue I am running into is the ID obviously causes the browser to jump. Is there some syntax I am not aware of that would keep the browser in place? Sort of defeats the purpose I suppose of an ID. I need each of those DIV elements (audio/video) to replace one another without jumping or moving one below the other when a user clicks either audio or video. Does that make sense?

Comment: You're very welcome. As for the ability to prevent the page jumping to the anchor there isn't really a clean solution; it's possible but messy using links and URL fragments/hashes. The typical check box hack would work, but would involve adding extraneous html.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain js way to do it. I am making a few assumptions here (about your markup).

```
function doMagic() {

    let urlType = window.location.href,
        audio =  document.getElementById('audio'),
        video =  document.getElementById('video');

    if (urlType.split('#')[1] === 'audio'{ //turn it into an array of two, split at the hash
        audio.style.display = 'block';
        video.style.display = 'none';
    }

    if (urlType.split('#')[1] === 'video'{
        audio.style.display = 'none';
        video.style.display = 'block';
    }

}

// assuming you have a button element for this

let videoBtn = document.getElementById('vidBtn'),
    audBtn = document.getElementById('audBtn');

vidBtn.addEventListener('click', function() { doMagic(); }); 
audBtn.addEventListener('click', function() { doMagic(); });
```

Both event listeners calls the same function. If your buttons have the same class then you can just simplify this to one event listener.

```
// assuming your buttons have the class name "myBtn"
let theBtn = document.getElementByClass('myBtn');

theBtn.addEventListener('click', function() { doMagic(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I have found was not done with plain javascript but with a framework called jquery. You could learn more about jquery from their [website](http://api.jquery.com), or from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/).
Below is the code.

```js
$("#audio").click(function(){
  $("#audio").toggleClass("active");
  $("#video").toggleClass("active");

 });
 $("#video").click(function(){
  $("#video").toggleClass("active");
  $("#audio").toggleClass("active");
 });
```

```css
.active{
   background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="video" class = "active" style="position: static; visibility: visible; overflow: visible; display: block;">MY VIDEO PLAYER</div>
<br>
<div id="audio" style="position: static; overflow: hidden; display: block;">MY AUDIO PLAYER</div>
```

First, we check when the element with id audio is clicked then we toggle between the class of active and inactive for the video id and audio id.
Similarly, when we check for the id video to be clicked we toggle the active class between the video id and audio id.
I hope this helped :)